# Linux Router for One Application using iptables

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tcp, iptables-redirect

I have 3 machines:
Router 192.168.229.4
Server 192.168.229.2 
Client 192.168.229.3

on the server there is a TCP file server running on port 1234. I want to redirect all the client-server-client traffic via the router machine. Using iptables I was able to do some redirection. The client send the request and it  redirect it to the router but the server answer directly to the client.

Those are the commands:
On the client 192.168.229.3:

```
 iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.229.4
```

On the router:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.229.2:1234
```

What should be the command to run on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you are missing is on the router:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```